# Put private key in application.yml with variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, rsa

I am using a RSA Private key in my code. I have put it in application.yml in spring boot application.

```
   privateKey: |
             -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
             Key data
             -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

This is working fine.

Now I am externalizing the keys to a secrets file. So I have created  a variable which will take it from server, if not use the current key as default.

```
   privateKey: ${PRIVATE_KEY:|
             -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
             Key data
             -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----}
```

**PRIVATE_KEY here is the variable in secrets file.**

But it is not working. I think it should be some other format.

I need two things:
1. how to put the variable in yml file and default value for key
2. How should I put it in secrets file.

Let me know if you need more details from my side.

Comment: `${PRIVATE_KEY}` instead of `${PRIVATE_KEY:` you should pass current RSA + ---`-------BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY ------ ` + whatever on `PRIVATE_KEY`.

Comment: @JonathanJohx Can you please elaborate more. Also i want to put default key for local

Comment: I added an answer, done

Answer (score 0):

First, you need export `RSA private key` directly.
you have a file which contains RSA private key, for example, `private-key.pem` contains this RSA private key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEA04up8hoqzS1+APIB0RhjXyObwHQnOzhAk5Bd7mhkSbPkyhP1 ... 
iWlX9HNavcydATJc1f0DpzF0u4zY8PY24RVoW8vk+bJANPp1o2IAkeajCaF3w9nf 
q/SyqAWVmvwYuIhDiHDaV2A== 
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
```

Then you can export by following way:

```
export PRIVATE_KEY=`cat private-key.pem`
```

Once this is added on environment variables then you can use it in you properties, directly.

```
privateKey: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

Comment: You have created a secret file private-key.pem and called it from application.yml but what if i want to read it from a secret file where my all centralized configurations are available.  My Requirement is, I want to read it from secret file as a string and not from .pem file

Comment: Okay, could you please create a new question based on what you want to do? So I can help you

Comment: @VikashkumarYadav Did you find the answer to your question

Comment: @JonathanJOhx I need an answer to this also

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta open a question or ping me to my email of my profile, kind regards.

Comment: @JonathanJOhx I have created a separate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61053525/rsa-private-key-in-secrets-file-in-a-centralized-configurations